# Coldfusion MultiSelection box without cfselect persisting selection after post

Tags: coldfusion-8

what I am attempting to accomplish here is fill a multiselect box with a list of items which this code does that part of this. 
What it is not doing is if I select more than 1 item in the list and try to submit the form it will not keep the same items selected in the list.

If I only select 1 item and submit the form that one item does remain selected though. 
This is my first week using coldfusion and this is my first hurdle I am sure at this point it is something pretty stupid and simple I am forgetting to do here but I have been coding all day and my eyes are crossing. I hope someone out there will point me in the right direction on this

```
 <select id="equipmentstatus1" name="equipmentstatus1" multiple="multiple">
 <cfloop list="#trim(cfleqstatus)#" delimiters="#chr(13)##chr(10)#" index="data">
 <cfset counter++>
 <cfoutput><option value="#rows[counter][1]#" <cfif form.equipmentstatus1 EQ rows[counter][1]> selected="selected"</cfif>>#rows[counter][2]#</option></cfoutput>


 </cfloop>
 </select>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your FORM value is going to contain a list of items, not a single item. So you need to change your if statement from this:

```
<cfif form.equipmentstatus1 EQ rows[counter][1]>
```

to this:

```
<cfif ListFind(form.equipmentstatus1, rows[counter][1])>
```

That will check the list of items in `FORM.equipmentstatus1` and try to find the current row's value in that list. if it finds it, it will return true.